# Fallo del comando dnf, no puedo instalar nada en Fedora 34

Tags: linux, sqlite, fedora

Cuando quiero instalar un programa, por ejemplo, python-devel, no me deja, me salta un error de I/O relacionada con una base de datos sqlite

`# dnf install python-devel`

```
Error: Ha fallado la carga del repositorio 'code'
Descartando repositorios: code
Última comprobación de caducidad de metadatos hecha hace 1:09:33, el dom 18 jul 2021 18:56:09.
History database is not writable: SQLite error on "/var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite": Executing an SQL statement failed: disk I/O error
History database is not writable: SQLite error on "/var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite": Executing an SQL statement failed: disk I/O error
Error: SQLite error on "/var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite": Executing an SQL statement failed: disk I/O error
```

Comment: uso dnf, `dnf install python-devel`, dice Fallo del comando **DNF**

Comment: There seems to be a problem with repo "code".  Can you install packages by disabling "code" with something like `dnf install --disablerepo=code python-devel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya lo encontré, la solucion es eliminar el archivo history.db
las consecuencias es que se eliminaran su historial de transacciones